# How to stop execution of infinite loop with exception handling?

Tags: python, loops, exception, infinite-loop

Say I ran this code in Python:

```
 while True:
     try:
         anything that doesn't break loop
     except: pass
```

How would I ever get it to stop? (Note: I suspect this isn't one of those times where I should learn by testing).

Of course in reality I would use a `break` statement. This is a theoretical question; how could one break this loop if even a KeyboardInterrupt is passed?

Comment: have you ever tried using `break` ?

Comment: I didn't get what is your intention of code. if you want to run until some exception happens then break the loop, then you can do this: {>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")}

Comment: The question was theoretical, not practical. Of course in reality I would use `break`, but I was wondering what my options were in case I wrote `pass` instead of `break` after the except as I have done here.

Answer (score 5):

break should do the trick

```
while True:
     try:
        print("Hello")
        break
     except: pass
```

depending upon wherever you would like to stop the flow of the program you can use it, inside the try block or in the except block

```
while True:
         try:
            print("Hello")

         except: 
              pass
              break
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written would never stop. You need to add a `break` statement somewhere to exit the loop. For example, if I wanted to exit the loop when there is an exception, I would do:

```
while True:
    try:
        # anything that doesn't break loop
    except: 
        break
```

If I wanted to exit the loop after the try block, I would do:

```
while True:
    try:
        # anything that doesn't break loop
        break
    except: 
        pass
```